# Highlight entire div when it's inside table

Tags: html, css, highlight

I'm trying to highlight a div section which is inside of a table, but it seems it's limited to the width of the table. The part after the scroll is not highlighted.

I can add styles in the div, e.g: "`width:400px !important`", but I don't know in advance what the width will be.

Is there any simple solution for this?

```css
.area1{
    border:1px solid;
    height:200px;
    overflow:scroll;
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.area1Content{
    height:500px;
    font-size: 16px;
   white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
 <div id="area1Id" class="area1">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td style="min-width:300px; max-width:300px"><div id="area1ContentId" class="area1Content">
        <div style="BACKGROUND-COLOR:cyan;">Test long text sentence that will exceed the box width. I  want that all the sentence will be highlighed</div>
      </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you're trying to do by adding `inline-block` to `.area1Content`:

```css
.area1{
   border:1px solid;
   height:200px;
   overflow:scroll;
   float: left;
   font-size: 16px;
}
.area1Content{
   height:500px;
   font-size: 16px;
   white-space:nowrap;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
 <div id="area1Id" class="area1">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td style="min-width:300px; max-width:300px"><div id="area1ContentId" class="area1Content">
        <div style="BACKGROUND-COLOR:cyan;">Test long text sentence that will exceed the box width. I  want that all the sentence will be highlighed</div>
      </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment:  Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

I see 3 solutions :

1. Either use a `<span>` instead of a `<div>` to contain your text.
2. Either use `display:inline-block` on the same `div`
3. Cleaner variation of the second solution : add `display:inline-block` to your `area1ContentId`class in the css.

```css
.area1{
    border:1px solid;
    height:200px;
    overflow:scroll;
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.area1Content{
    height:500px;
    font-size: 16px;
   white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="area1Id" class="area1">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td style="min-width:300px; max-width:300px"><div id="area1ContentId" class="area1Content">
        <div style="BACKGROUND-COLOR:cyan; display:inline-block">Test long text sentence that will exceed the box width. I  want that all the sentence will be highlighed</div>
      </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Note also that instead of using the `style`attribute I'd rather define a class in the CSS